# How do I link reversely in my href attribute

Tags: html

I have a file (homepage.html) outside folder name "Login 101"and I want to go in homepage.html when I click the home logo. How do I put link in href reversely in my HTML5 file.

Login.html

```
<a href = homepage.html"><img src = "Home2.png" alt = "home" id = "home" >
```

Comment: href = "/homepage.html" ?

Comment: I added it already but Its still not working